# AND/OR Statement in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Does anyone know how to transcribe this in Tableau:

```
WHERE DATE(created) = '2021-01-01'
AND (source = 'T' OR (a.promo = 'TK' AND source != 'T'))
```

Basically, I'm validating if source equals to "T" and grabbing all those results, but sometimes a promo but does not get flagged under the "T" source.

Is there a way to have filter that validates under this nested WHERE clause?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you wanting a Tableau calculated field in the place of a SQL WHERE statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting to use a calculated field in the place of SQL then:

```
IF DATE([created]) = '2021-01-01'
AND ([source] = 'T' OR ([promo] = 'TK' AND [source] <> 'T'))
THEN [measure or dimension] END
```

That's assuming that the fields in Tableau end up being given those names.

EDIT

The calculated field above works by just ignoring data that doesn’t meet the conditions, which is very flexible — effectively pulling the condition from the WHERE clause into the SELECT clause of the query that Tableau generates.

In some other cases, you really do want to first filter to a set of data and then calculate on the resulting rows — either for performance or logic reasons.

In that case, you can define a boolean calculated field with just the condition, put it on the Filter shelf, and choose to filter to records whether the calculated field evaluates to True.

Both approaches are useful.

Comment: Ah! Thank you sir! 
Last question, but why did you define [source] <> 'T' and not [source] != 'T'? 
Is there a difference (got the same result) or syntax preference at this point?

Comment: No problem! I just went with what I knew worked in Tableau. But if that works then good deal!